# spring aop that intercepts org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#invoke

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspect, spring-cache

I have tried the following code , but it does not work:

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
public class CacheAspect {

    @Around("execution(public * org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(..))")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        //CLASS_CACHE.set(signature.getReturnType());
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

**P.S.** I am sure `CacheInterceptor` is a spring managed bean.

Comment: What menas "does not work"?

Comment: @Jens `CacheInterceptor#invoke` cannot be intercepted.

Comment: Why do you want to intercept and interceptor?!

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to collect method information into ThreadLocal and use it somewhere else.

Comment: But do you really want to intercept the interceptor?

Comment: if you want to collect cache statistics, there's an easier way to do that. You can't intercept an interceptor AFAIK

Answer (score 7):

After some experimenting, I find that replacing the spring built in `CacheInterceptor` with a user defined one can solve my problem.
Here is the code in case someone has similar requirments.

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableCaching
  @Profile("test")
  public class CacheConfig {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisClientTemplate redisClientTemplate) {
      return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(redisClientTemplate, "test");
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheOperationSource cacheOperationSource() {
      return new AnnotationCacheOperationSource();
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheInterceptor cacheInterceptor() {
      CacheInterceptor interceptor = new MyCacheInterceptor();
      interceptor.setCacheOperationSources(cacheOperationSource());
      return interceptor;
    }
  }
```

MyCacheInterceptor.java, which shares the same logic with `CacheAspect`:

```
  public class MyCacheInterceptor extends CacheInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
      Method method = invocation.getMethod();
      //CLASS_CACHE.set(signature.getReturnType());
      return super.invoke(invocation);
    }
  }
```

The spring built in `CacheInterceptor` bean can be found in `ProxyCachingConfiguration` class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this solution is help me to use a cache provider put method in my custom interceptor , which enable me to set eviction time on put  , which is not part of spring cache abstraction - and  I added @Primary on cacheInterceptor() bean method , thanks!